# Routing an endpoint call to a certain database based on query string param with LoopBack v3 node.js framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

As of now I created a Model, DataSource, Model-Config association to use the default LoopBack functionality. This way I am able to do the following: https://localhost:3000/api/myendpoint to do a simple get request that will return everything and it works fine. However, I need to make it so there is an additional query string param called client such as: https://localhost:3000/api/myendpoint?client=clientxyz. When the call is made will I be able to retrieve this query string param and tell loopback to still use all of its default functionality such as filtering, sorting, etc.., but override the datasource somehow basically changing "database": "client_name" to "database": "clientxyz" on the fly?

**Model**
myendpoint.json
myendpoint.js

**Datasource**

```
  "my-ds": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "database": "client_name", // Needs to be dynamic based on query string param
    "password": "xyz",
    "name": "my-ds",
    "debug": false,
    "user": "admin",
    "connector": "mysql"
  }
```

**Model-Config**

```
  "myendpoint": {
    "dataSource": "my-ds",
    "public": true
  }
```

Comment: Changing the database of a database connection would be entirely the realm of the connector.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this programmatically in server.js file using something like this..

```
var databaseName = "client_name";    

var mongoDB = new DataSource({
    connector: require('loopback-connector-mongodb'),
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    database: databaseName
});
```

More details in official docs.. http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Advanced-topics-data-sources.html#creating-a-data-source-programmatically